# How to change the design of tab in terminator?

Tags: terminator

When I open new tab in terminator, the tabs look very ugly. How to change their appearances?

In gnome-terminal, I can change their looks by editting `$HOME/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`, but it's not working for terminator.

**UPDATE:**
The tabs is a little bit thick and the background color is white so it's too conspicuous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** terminator also uses gtk in background so check your version of terminator using:

```
terminator -v
```

If it is version `0.97` then make changes in the `gtk2` file because it uses `gtk2`, and Ubuntu uses `gtk3` so you have to change in both files.

For the theme check use:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme
```

then change the following in `/usr/share/themes/<YOUR_THEME>/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`:

```
style "notebook_bg" {
  bg[NORMAL] = shade (1.02, @bg_color)
  bg[ACTIVE] = shade (0.97, @bg_color)
  fg[ACTIVE] = mix (0.8, @fg_color, shade (0.97, @bg_color))
}
```

Replace `@bg_color` in `bg[NORMAL]` with a color of your choice, *e.g.*, `"#F98686"`(quotes required).

To make changes in gtk3, open `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` (if it doesn't exist then create it):

```
TerminalWindow .notebook tab:active{
  background-color: @bg_color;
}
```

Save it and reopen the terminal.

For other change :

```
right click on terminator screen --> preferences
```

Here  you can change terminator appearance that you want to change like custom profile, layouts, plug-ins, colors, etc. Once you add a new configuration it will create configuration files under `~/.config/terminator/`.

Edit :
for color change :

```
preferences --> profiles--> colors
```

for layout change :

```
preferences --> profiles--> Layouts--> Add--> give name --> close
```

It will create config file `~/.config/terminator/config` 
open this file using

```
gedit ~/.config/terminator/config
```

Change size and other things that you want in this file. You can also change color from this file.

reference :[link](http://weishi.github.io/blog/2014/09/27/change-tab-color-in-terminator-and-ubuntu-terminal/)

**Note :** Kindly re-launch the application for the changes to take effect.

Comment: thank you for you answer. But can you tell me how exactly to change the tab design?  Cuz all I know is I can change the tab position.

Comment: what you want exactly color change or different layout or other ?

Comment: I want to change the background color and the height of the tabs.

Comment: Is it possible to change the background color of tabs?

Comment: i updated answer !! i hope it will work

Comment: I am sorry to ask you elementary question, but what theme to choose for <YOUR_THEME>?

Comment: try `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme`

Comment: I was able to change the background color of tab by modifying gtkrc but have no idea how to change the height of tabs. I have to figure out how gtkrc is written. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer seems to be quite outdated and doesn't work with newer Ubuntu versions.

To change the look of tabs in terminator have a look at the following post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50082359/terminator-1-91-change-tab-theme-color-using-gtk3-css

The following settings worked for me:

```
/* ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css */

.terminator-terminal-window notebook tab {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
.terminator-terminal-window notebook tab:checked {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #459cc4;
}
.terminator-terminal-window notebook tab button {
  padding: 0;
}
```

The following blog shows some more customization settings:

http://blog.nabam.net/workstation/2017/09/15/terminator_tabs

Comment: This was the solution that finally worked for me. ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, terminator 1.91